# Rearranging pixels on a video in realtime in Quartz Composer

Tags: quartz-composer

Does anyone know a good resource related to remapping the pixels in a video in realtime using Quartz Composer?  I've read through the programming guide, but it doesn't have all the information I need...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of "remapping" do you have in mind?

If you have a mathematical expression for, given the location of an output pixel, determining which input pixel(s) combine to form that output pixel, then Core Image is probably what you're looking for.  Check out the `Core Image Kernel` patch --- feed your image data through that patch, then go to its Settings panel to customize the pixel shader.

Comment: Awesome, I will definitely check that out right now.  I have to convert between two arbitrary coordinate systems, i.e. pixel (10,10)'s data is now pixel (130, 45)'s data in the new view.

Comment: So I've been having a back and forth with Apple about this, and they seem to think it won't serve my purposes.  I literally need to grab a handful of pixels from one video, and display those elsewhere on another video.  Whatdo you think?