# Downsampling realtime video in iOS iPhone app at 60 fps

Tags: ios, real-time, avfoundation, video-processing

I am trying to downsample realtime video on iOS device (taking every second pixel for example) with one condition: doing it in 60 fps.

The resolution may be lowered, video screen's view can be only a small rectangle (about 200x200px). The result then should be previewed on the screen.

I have been using the excellent 2012 WWDC RosyWriter example as a starting point.
But after many hours of searching, I cannot find even one tutorial nor a github project of someone who already did the same and can explain how this can be done. I have screened all the relevant questions in StackOverflow over and over without any success. I'm looking for a code sample, good answer or a quick reference to a tutorial on this subject.

Relevant but still unanswered questions:

- [iOS AVFoundation - Converting video into images at 60 fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946534/ios-avfoundation-converting-video-into-images-at-60-fps)
- [Rearranging pixels on a video in realtime in Quartz Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297501/rearranging-pixels-on-a-video-in-realtime-in-quartz-composer)
- [Skip over frames while processing video on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242707/skip-over-frames-while-processing-video-on-ios?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [SimpleVideoFilter](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/SimpleVideoFilter) example in [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage).

Then eliminate the Sepia filter with something like this just to get a preview:

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[videoCamera addTarget:filterView];
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

This is the beginning of what Brad is suggested in the comments:

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter* filter = [[GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter alloc] init];
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[videoCamera addTarget:filter];
[filter forceProcessingAtSize:self.view.frame.size];
[filter addTarget:filterView];    
[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

The output from the filter would also be sent to a GPUImageMovieWriter.  The SimpleVideoFilter example covers it.

Comment: This won't do any actual downsampling, but if you used a GPUImageLanczosResamplingFilter with `-forceProcessingAtSize:` for your target image size, you should be able to do fast, high-quality downsampling.

Comment: I extended the answer slightly to include the downsampling (sans video file writer).  Thanks for the suggestion and the framework Brad.